# Featured image metabox not showing up

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails

I have a theme installed on WordPress Multisite 3.5.1 which has a one custom post. Now I wanted to have two more so I have created them. Everything is working besides one thing. The featured image metabox is not showing up. I have added it to custom post

```
   $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $md_cssitems_rewrite ),
        'menu_icon' =>  get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin/assets/images/icon-porfolio-16x16.png' ,
        'query_var' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 8,
        //features support in Pofolio post type  
        'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','thumbnail','page-attributes')
      );
```

I also have read I might need to activate it using in my functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails',array('custom-post1','custom-post2') );
```

I also have checked in screen options and it is not hidden there.

I am running out of ideas. What else might be wrong?

Comment: Are capabilities being set somewhere in your functions.php, that prevent certain roles uploading media? This is a stab in the dark though. Possibly some code is actively removing that meta box? I would disable all plugins to see if that fixes the problem. If it does, reactivate one by one to isolate the culprit. If it's not a plugin, it's probably some kind of override in your theme.

Comment: Does the Featured Image work in Posts and Pages? Can you post the whole hook and function where you are doing the `register_post_type`?

Comment: I have updated my qyestion. @vancoder, it cannot be capabilities as it has a capability type=post.

Comment: @brasofolio - yes posts and pages do have featured image metabox visible.

Comment: In a clean WP install using a standard theme, your code works (skipping the variables that are not declared in your code snippet). So, again, I suggest you try and isolate the issue by deactivating/reactivating plugins.