# featured image metabox not showing on the default post types edit page

Tags: post-thumbnails

I can't get the Featured Image metabox to show up on the edit page for the default `post` and `page` post types.

Though as opposed to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92455/featured-image-metabox-not-showing-up), it *does* work for the custom post type I've created using a plugin. It just doesn't work with the default ones.

I've read the [Codex Article on Post_thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails).

Added the following line to the current theme's `functions.php` and to that plugin I was working on:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
```

Also been checking the screen options on the top right of the edit page and the checkbox for the Featured Image is not even there.

Where do I check to see if something else does not overwrite that? Please help

Comment: By default post types "post" and "page" do have support for featured image meta box. You don't need to add some thing in function.php for that. I would suggest try deactivating your plugins one by one and check if it gets back.

Comment: @MohammadMursaleen thanks for reminding me about the disable-plugins approach, will see if that makes a difference and update the question

Comment: @MohammadMursaleen that was it, thank you. If you post that as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default post types "post" and "page" do have support for featured image meta box. You don't need to add some thing in function.php for that. This might be happening due to some plugin confliction.

I would suggest try deactivating your plugins one by one and check if it gets back.

Comment: It was a plugin issue indeed: my plugin had the following code `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'my_post_type' ) );` and it turns out this enabled the thumbs for that type only, removing the support from the others. The solution was to remove the second argument, i.e. `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`, this enabled the pics everywhere. Accepting this answer because disabling the plugins was what I did to narrow down the issue. Thanks a lot @Mohammad

Answer (score 3):

1. You don't need to pass an array to the function if you want Post Thumbnails everywhere. Just pass the function without arguments:

   add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
2. Maybe you just need to change the post options.
   On the top right corner of the "edit post/edit page" page you have a button called "Options". There you can choose different areas to show or hide. Did you hide the Featured Image Metabox by mistake?